# How to use Onchange with date field in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, onchange

## field declaration

```
    price=fields.Integer(string="Price")
    service_date=fields.Date(string="Last servicing date")
    service_charge=fields.Integer(string="Last Service Charge")
    total_charge=fields.Integer(string="Total Spent")
```

## onchange Function in which servie_date is used as argument

```
    @api.onchange('service_date')
    def _onchange_total_charge(self):
        if self.total_charge > 0:
            self.total_charge+=self.service_charge
        else:
            self.total_charge=self.price+self.service_charge
```

Comment: Is that field in the form view? If not -> add it (invisible is possible, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@api.onchange('service_date')
@api.depends('service_date')
def _onchange_total_charge(self):
    if self.total_charge > 0:
        self.total_charge += self.service_charge
    else:
        self.total_charge = self.price + self.service_charge
```

Try to re-write the code like this

Comment: Ok. Thanx for your support

Answer (score 2):

I've used your code it works on my odoo instance. Please make sure that you call the same in field in your xml file. you can also use compute field to get your calculation done.

Comment: Thanx  Thayif. i will try and let you know if it's not working